# Get data in java when http request sent by curl command

Tags: java, web-services, curl, httprequest

Does anyone know how to get data in java when http request sent by curl command "--data"?
For example :

```
curl --data { Name : username , Gender : gender , Age : age } -X PUT http://localhost:8080/user/folder -v
```

I want to know how to get data  `{ Name :username ,..... age }` using curl command --data.
I use the method in REST Web service which is used jersey framework and java .

Answer (score 0):

Since you PUT data when you use curl this way, all you need to do is to implement a PUT request handler. In theory at least :)

Something like

```
@PUT
@Path("/user/folder")      
@Consumes("application/json")
public void receiveData(String data) { 
    ......
}
```

edit: didn't see the -X PUT at first. you want a PUT handler not a POST handler.

Comment: hi deadsven, i aldy have PUT method . so I just need to write variable "String data" in put method?Coz i am new to web service.thanks

Comment: yes sudo, the request body should be sent in into the data variable then.

Comment: btw for upload i used curl -T /home/student/a.jpg --data { Name: name....} http://localhost:8080/user/a.jpg . For that case I aldy have "String content" variable for upload ,so i need another variable to capture --data. But can I examine which one belong to which? thanks